# Fried chicken variation

Tags: chicken, frying

Suppose I am making KFC-style chicken at home.

What would be the problem if I

1. marinade the chicken with spices
2. get the pieces boiled before coating
3. use liquid batter rather than dry powder for coating

??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There a numerous variations for making fried chicken.  There is no problem with any of your steps.  Recipes include marination, cooking before frying, and liquid batters.  It probably won't be KFC-style, but it can be delicious.